# Is there any information on the H7 language?

Tags: programming-languages

I was speaking with a friend of mine who works in healthcare.  He mentioned a language for communication between disparate systems that is specific to healthcare.  I believe he called it "h7".  It struck me as something of an XML or XML derivative.  I work in healthcare, but have never heard of it.

In searching google I don't see anything about "H7" the programming language.  Have you heard of it?  What is it and where can I find information on it?

Comment: This would be a good question for the [Healthcare Industry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41370/healthcare-industry?referrer=0FgbVsKaId7Z_15aCbzplg2) stack exchange. If you're interested, considering joining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like an interchange format, not a language;

Health Level Seven Standard - An application Protocol for Electronic Data Exchange in Healthcare Environments

http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/ansiapproved.cfm?ref=nav